# Android parsing XML with YQL data

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, yql

I am trying to do a simple APP that parses Currency data from Yahoo finance using their YQL query language.  I tried parsing data with Google's finance API and it works fine but when I try it with Yahoo's URL it freezes before I even get to my parsing algorithm which is very strange.

```
package com.sfc.watcher;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ForexActivity extends Activity {

    String temp1;
    String temp2;
    TableLayout tl1;

    View temp3;

    private static final String URL1 ="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(\"" ;
    private static final String URL2="\")&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";


    // This TAG is used for logging
    private static final String TAG = "ForexWatcherActivity";

    // These String constants refer to the XML elements we will be displaying
    private static final String NAME = "Name";
    private static final String RATE = "Rate";
    private static final String DATE = "Date";
    private static final String TIME = "Time";
    private static final String ASK = "Ask";
    private static final String BID = "Bid";


    // This String refers to the attribute we are collecting for each element in
    // our XML
    private static final String DATA = "data";

        // This HashMap will store, in key-value pairs, the currency data we receive.
    private HashMap<String, String> hmCurrencyData = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // This is the edit control that users will key into
    private EditText edittext1 = null;

        // This is the button that, when pressed, will request currency price data.
    private Button button1 = null;

        // This variable will hold the currency symbol value the user has keyed in.
    private String symbol = "";



    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        temp3=v;
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.edit:

                return true;
            case R.id.delete:

                tl1.removeView(temp3);   
                return true;
            case R.id.save:

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.forex);

        tl1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bn_retrieve);
        edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_symbol1);
        edittext1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            }


            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

                        // here we respond to users key input events

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {

                // collect the text from the edit control, and trim off spaces.
                symbol = edittext1.getText().toString().trim();

                // if the user has entered at least one character, enable the
                // bnRetrieve button.
                // otherwise, disable it.
                button1.setEnabled(symbol.length() > 0);

            }

        });

        final EditText edittext2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_symbol2);
        //First spinner for input forex

        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id1.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.forex_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SellListener());

        //Second spinner for Output forex

        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id2.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.forex_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new BuyListener());

        // Capture our button from layout


        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bn_convert);
        // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {       
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Selling "+ "$"+ edittext2.getText().toString()+ " "+ temp1 + " Buying "+ "$"+ temp2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }
    public class SellListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
            temp1=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
          // Do nothing.
        }
    }
    public class BuyListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
            temp2=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
          // Do nothing.
        }
    }

    public void retrieveQuote(View vw) {

        // our "symbol" variable already has the text from the edSymbol view via
        // the onTextChanged() event capture.
        String request = URL1  + symbol + URL2;
        CurrencyRetrieveTask task = new CurrencyRetrieveTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { request });

    }
    private class CurrencyRetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private static final String TAG = "CurrencyRetrieveTask";

        private ProgressDialog pDlg = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");

            hideKeyboard();

            pDlg = createProgressDialog(ForexActivity.this,
                    getString(R.string.retrieving));

            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            // Remember that the array will only have one String
            String url = urls[0];

            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));

                String s = "";

                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(s);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

            readResponse(response);

            displayResponse();

            pDlg.dismiss();

        }

    }

    private void hideKeyboard() {

        // hide the soft keyboard, if it is currently visible.
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext1.getWindowToken(),
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

    }

    private ProgressDialog createProgressDialog(final Context context,
            final String message) {

        Log.i(TAG, "createProgressDialog");

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

        progressDialog.setMessage(message);
        progressDialog.setProgressDrawable(getWallpaper());
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        return progressDialog;
    }

    private void readResponse(String response) {

        Log.i(TAG, "displayResponse");

        // initialize our HashMap, resetting it if it was previously used.


        hmCurrencyData = new HashMap<String, String>();

        try {

            String elementName = "";
            String elementValue = "";
            String nameSpace = "";

         StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(response);


            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(xmlReader);


            elementName = parser.getName();

            while (!elementName.equals("rate"))
            {
                parser.nextTag();
                elementName = parser.getName();
            }





        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }








    private void updateTextView(String name, TableRow Row) {

        if(hmCurrencyData.containsKey(name))
        {
        TextView TV1= new TextView(getApplicationContext());        
        TV1.setText(hmCurrencyData.containsKey(name) ? hmCurrencyData.get(name) : "");

        TV1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        Row.addView(TV1); 
        }
    }

    private void displayResponse() {

        Log.i(TAG, "displayResponse");

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);

        updateTextView(NAME, tr);
        updateTextView(RATE, tr);
        updateTextView(DATE, tr);
        updateTextView(TIME, tr);
        updateTextView(ASK, tr);
        updateTextView(BID, tr);


        registerForContextMenu(tr);

        tl1.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  



    }



}
```

Comment: no need to pass array...Use `task.execute(request);`

Comment: I don't think thats the problem, i tried and its not working

Answer (score 1):

The table is not defined. The URL returns this error:

> No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.xchange

When run in the browser:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22%22%29&diagnostics=true
```